# Cast exception in native sql query using hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have a sql query using tables in it. the result set is return to a bean class which is not mapped to a table in database. the code is here:

```
    SQLQuery q2=ss.createSQLQuery("select tbl_policy.policyNum as POLICYNUM FROM     tbl_policy join tbl_product on tbl_policy.FK_productId = tbl_product.pk_product_id join tbl_code  on tbl_policy.FK_codeId = tbl_code.PK_codeId join tbl_agriyear on tbl_policy.FK_agriYearId = tbl_agriyear.pk_agriyear_id where tbl_policy.FK_naturalInsurantId = :p1 and tbl_agriyear.AGRIYEAR =:p2");
q2.addScalar("POLICYNUM", Hibernate.STRING);
List<SearchPolicyBean> lsql = (List<SearchPolicyBean>)q2.list();
```

bean class name is: SearchPolicyBean
when I run it, in this line

```
System.out.println("Finalllll "+lsql.get(0).getPOLICYNUM());
```

this error appears:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to BO.SearchPolicyBean
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for getting first element:

setPolicyNum((String) ((Object[])polList.get(i))[0]);

Answer (score 0):

```
addScalar(String columnAlias) 
          Is to Declare a scalar query result.
```

You declared it as a String   here `q2.addScalar("POLICYNUM", Hibernate.STRING);`

So obviously the query results a String list not  your  SearchPolicyBean pojos .

If you are expectiong an list of your pojo classe you have to use

```
q2.addEntity(SearchPolicyBean.Class);
```

And change your query according.

Comment: I saw in a sample, add scalar was used for classifying attributes in a POJO class

Comment: addEntity is used for a database mapped bean. But my bean class is not mapped to a database table.